# How to write a switch statement in jQuery/Javascript to test if an element has a particular class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, if-statement, switch-statement

This is the structure of the if-else statement I am using:

```
$('.myclass a').click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('class1')) {
        //do something
   } else if ($(this).hasClass('class2')) {
        //do something
   } else if ($(this).hasClass('class3')) {
        //do something
   } else if ($(this).hasClass('class4')) {
        //do something
   } else {
        //do something
   }
});
```

There are quite a number of cases already and I thought using a switch statement would be neater. How do I do it in jQuery/javascript?

Comment: does `.myclass a` only have a single class?

Comment: Why don't you bind the click event handler directly to the links with the corresponding class?

Comment: @sberry2A - It has only 1 class.

Comment: @Felix Kling - I can try that too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that an user could have more than one class. Otherwise you could do:

```
$('.myclass a').click(function() {
   var className = $(this).attr('class');
   switch(className){
      case 'class1':
     //put your cases here
   }
});
```

Comment: Not a good idea to use a variable named `class` as I believe that is a reserved word in Javascript (reserved for future use).  Change it to `className` or something besides `class`.

Comment: this saves a lot of code but what if $(this) has more than one class?

Comment: I don't think this is very efficient since if have multiple classes on the same class attribute, I'm no very sure that it would work since you would've been returning all the classes in a single string line. your returned value in this case would be "class1 class2 class3", that means that your cases would never be true

Answer (score 26):

Try this.  Not much cleaner, but still a switch statement.

```
$('.myclass a').click(function() {
    switch (true) {
      case $(this).hasClass('class1'):
        // do stuff
        break;
      case $(this).hasClass('class2'):
        // do stuff
        break;
      case $(this).hasClass('class3'):
        // do stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tesserex: Yeah, it's not the greatest.  I like Nicola's much better.

Comment: This works for me.. I was thinking same too... Thanks

Comment: @XyanEwing How is Nicola's better? This works if there are more classes in the class attribute, Nicola's fails on that case.

Comment: This is more accurate then the accepted answer. Imagine if `element1` has class `class1.class2` and `element2` has class `class3.class4` and you want to test which element has class `class1` whatever other class list on each element

Answer (score 5):

I think the cleanest way might just be this:

```
$('.myclass a.class1').click(function() {
   // code to process class1
});

$('.myclass a.class2').click(function() {
   // code to process class2
});

$('.myclass a.class3').click(function() {
   // code to process class3
});

$('.myclass a.class4').click(function() {
   // code to process class4
});
```

If you had a zillion of them, you could even put them in a data structure like this:

```
// to define them all
var classHandlers = {
    class1: function() {
        // class1 code here
    },
    class2: function() {
        // class2 code here
    },
    class3: function() {
        // class3 code here
    },
    class4: function() {
        // class4 code here
    }
};

// to register them all
$.each(classHandlers, function(key, fn) {
    $('.myclass a.' + key).click(fn);
});
```

Since you've asked (in a comment) how you would do an event handler for the objects with no class name, here's how you could do that if you were looking for no class name:

```
$(".myclass a").not("[class]").click(function() {
    // code to handle objects with no class name here
});
```

I tested it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TAjKR/

Comment: I tried this one and this also works (looks cleaner). However, what if I want to do something on a '.myclass a' that has no class (on the switch statement, it's the default value)? Where do I attach the event handler?

Comment: I added to my answer one way to implement the default case of no class name.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that a single switch statement will help here, because one element can have multiple classes, and you cannot use elem.className to switch. An option is to structure the code in a more readable way, using a for statement in which to have switches...:

```
$('.myclass a').click(function() 
{
    var classes = ["class1", "class2", "class3","class4"];
    var self = $(this);
    for(var i =0, ii = classes.length;i<ii;i++)
    {
        var className = classes[i];
        if(self.hasClass(className))
        {
            switch(className)
            {
                case 'class1':
                    //code here... 
                break;
                case 'class2':
                    //code here... 
                break;      
                case 'class3':
                    //code here... 
                break;     
                case 'class4':
                    //code here... 
                break;
            }

        }
    }       
});
```

Comment: This is work, but it takes more a lot of action compared to to accepted or @Xyan Ewing's answer. Bcz this should be make an array and iterate them before find element hasclass `.something` . I believe this takes more memory too

Answer (score 0):

To check hasClass in an switch statement:

```
var elementClass;
var classCheck = $('#myElement').hasClass(elementClass)

switch(classCheck){
  case elementClass === 'foo':
     console.log('whatever');
     break;
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late and your user only has one class, but, if there was more than one class:

```
//<div class="foo bar"></div>
//<div class="other bar"></div>

switch(true) {
  case 'foo':
    true;
    break;
  case 'other':
    true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $("#isTest").click(function () {

   if($('div').is('.redColor')){
    $('div').addClass('blueColor');
   }

    });

    $("#hasClassTest").click(function () {

   if($('div').hasClass('.redColor')){
    $('div').addClass('blueColor');
   }

    });

 $("#reset").click(function () {
   location.reload();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .redColor {
   background:red;
  }
  .blueColor {
   background:blue;
  }
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>jQuery check if an element has a certain class</h1>

  <div class="redColor">This is a div tag with class name of "redColor"</div>

  <p>
  <button id="isTest">is('.redColor')</button>
  <button id="hasClassTest">hasClass('.redColor')</button>
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```